# How to list all tags used in a blog post using flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm new to Flask and SQLAlchemy and I want to ask that how can i add a page in which all tags that are used in a blog post are shown there.

Please Help. New to Programming.Thanks In Advance.

> #### Views.py

```
@blog.route('/tag')
def list_tag():
    tag_list = Post.query.all()
    return render_template('tags.html', tag_list=tag_list)
```

Comment: Can you describe what's wrong?  Is this producing an error or the wrong result?  Can you show the contents of `tags.html`?  Can you show `repr(Post.query.all())`?

Comment: I just didnt know that how to export the tags from the database and show it on the webpage `tags.html`